# Tasklist list in wait queue different than allocated by Binder

Tags: linux-kernel, android-binder

I am looking into Android Kernel Vulnerability disclosed by Google's Project Zero. Reproducing it for learning purposes on my mobile.

Question:

"somehow queue address is NOT the same as thread->wait.... that where UAF comes in, any ideas why? shouldn't be it the same? it is head of the list, isn't it?"

p0 link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=1942 
PoC: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/attachmentText?aid=414030

I had to adjust the PoC slightly ... to trigger it on my mobile kernel. I just want to see that queue address (remove wait queue) is the same as thread->wait , but it is not :( any ideas what I am missing?

Maybe you know why .. below some code + debug, checking out Android Binder UAF

Working without KASAN is a pain, also not to be able to debug kernel on the fly ... heheheh....

https://github.com/S3NEO/android_kernel_samsung_s3ve3g/blob/24c9b3454fddc6a5b332989cb4f4455c21867a42/drivers/staging/android/binder.c#L3222

thread->wait address and freed below taken from above function:

```
[87254.673335] wq queue:e4fb5398
[87254.673343] epoll struct:e4fb5380
[87254.673356] wq queue:e4fb5418
[87254.673362] epoll struct:e4fb5400
[87254.673389] binder_ioctl: 21697:21697 40046208 0
[87254.673396] iovec str size:8
[87254.673402] thread->wait:e5c5ed2c
[87254.673407] proc->wait:e5034268
[87254.673413] binder_free_thread size:252 worker_off:44
[87254.673421] freed thread:e5c5ed00
[87254.673859] ep_unregister_pollwait struct:e4fb5380 epi struct:e4fb5180
[87254.673915] ep_unregister_pollwait struct:e4fb5400 epi struct:e4fb5a80
[87254.673923] ep_unregister_pollwait list not empty
[87254.673929] whead before
[87254.673934] remove wait queue:e734d96c
[87254.673940] remove wait queue task list:e734d978
[87254.673946] ep_unregister_pollwait list not empty
[87254.673952] whead before
```

https://github.com/S3NEO/android_kernel_samsung_s3ve3g/blob/348ef929213854f5c7ce6b608e2ca0216d6bdce7/fs/eventpoll.c#L533

```
[87254.673957] remove wait queue:e734d9e4
[87254.673963] remove wait queue task list:e734d9f0


[87254.673989] ep_free
[87254.674000] ep_free
```

BUT somehow queue address is NOT the same as thread->wait.... that where UAF comes in, any ideas why? shouldn't be it the same? it is head of the list, isn't it?

Maybe above help, unless you cannot tell from it.

Thanks,